# AS3 NetConnection to MS Azure Media Services

Tags: actionscript-3, azure

I'm trying to publish a live web cam stream to an Azure Media Services channel. I have the channel configured and am using the rtmp ingest url in the NetConnection.connect method. 
I have my Flash AS3 setup to stream to an Adobe Media Server and it works fine. All I am doing so far is changing the URL to the Azure one. 
All I ever get is NetConnection.Connect.Failed 
If I use that same ingest url in wirecast I can stream my web cam fine. 
Any thoughts as to why the Flash version is failing?